# More than one SharedPreferences in a project

Tags: dart, flutter

Can I have two `SharedPreferences` file in Flutter, so that if I have to delete one file, second file remains the same.

I can only use

```
SharedPreferences.getInstance(); // I wish this accepts a string constructor too so that I can create different files.
```

So, does this `SharedPreference` returns a unique file every time I create it or what is the solution to create two files?

Comment: can you not save the same file twice and delete one of them while keeping the other? Doing so only needs one instance of `SharedPreference`

Comment: Someone favourited this question, I request him/her to also upvote it so that this can bring more people from community to answer. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need multiple files? Are you sure that you need more than one? What kind of data do you want to save?

Comment: Yes, I want 2 files, one for my settings and one for rest of my app. I know both can be done in one file but there is an option in my app that allows user to reset the settings, so i was thinking to delete the settings shared preferences file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there can be only one `SharedPreferences` file (although in Android, we can create multiple files but in iOS we can have just one file which is why Flutter can only support one file)

So, I have to use `SharedPreferences.remove()` method to get the things done.

Comment: Do you need a cross-platform solution, or is an Android-specific solution fine?

Comment: I need cross-platform solution.